# Help with my minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am on a mac and I just finished my Minecraft server. I would like to log into it, but when I go to direct connect and type in *:25565 it just says "Unknown Host".

Comment: Where is this server located? If it's being hosted on the same machine as the one you're trying to log into, you should replace "*" with localhost. If it's elsewhere, you need to identify the IP/hostname of the machine it is running on and replace * with that.

Comment: It is on the same machine and the server folder is on my desktop.

Comment: with localhost:25565 it said "java.net.ConnectExeption:Connection refused

Comment: how do i identify the hostname or Ip of my mac

Comment: Where are you hosting your server? If you are running directly from your Mac, localhost should work. Your IP is located at System Preferences -> Network. The IP should start with either 10.68 or 192.168

Answer (score 3):

The default port that Minecraft runs on is 25565 and the client assumes that port when connecting if none is listed. Since the server is running on the same machine as the client, you can connect to the server by typing the following in the field

```
localhost
```

If you want to connect to the server from a different machine, you should replace localhost with the ip address or hostname of the appropriate server. If Minecraft is running on a port other than 25565, connect with the following

```
localhost:<port>
```

You can identify the ip address of a mac by going to the command prompt and typing `ifconfig`

Comment: where do i find the command prompt? i just did a spotlight search and nothing came up

Comment: It might be called "terminal".

Comment: i used that and tons of stuff came up. what will it look like?

Comment: Most likely under your eth0 connection (this might vary depending on how your computer is configured). Look for the `inet addr`, which will be a short string of numbers. Something like `192.168.0.11`

Comment: it does not show that

Comment: PC: CMD - Command Prompt Mac/Linux: Terminal.

Comment: @Seldom As for finding your IP, goto System Preferences, Network, and click on the IP tab **(Clarification needed)** and it displays all IP information.